# Website changes my link target: how do I change it back?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, video

I'm using Instructure Canvas—a learning management system—to code a web page. I can use JavaScript but it has to be in an external file, not embedded in the HTML.

I want to have a few buttons linking to videos that show up in an iframe on the current page like so:

```
<a class="iframelink" href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/90612" target="vimeobox">watch</a>
```

The problem is that the learning management system changes the links to pop up in an external tab like so:

```
<a class="external" target="_blank" href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/90612">watch</a>
```

Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

After the learning management system has generated the video links, run the following JavaScript function:

```js
function changeLinks() {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
    var link = links[i];
    if (link.className == 'external') {
      link.className = 'iframelink';
      link.target = 'vimeobox';
    }
  }
}

changeLinks();
```

```html
<a class="external" target="_blank" href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/90612">watch</a>
```

This script takes all the anchor tags on the page that have `class="external"` and modifies them by changing the class and target.

Comment: you forget call _changeLinks_ in snippet

Comment: Awesome! Can I somehow target only links within a div?